# How to Git Un stage all staged files?

Tags: git, github

I need to **unstage** all staged files which I added by "**git add .**" what is the actual command to do this with out loosing any of my code updates of those added files all together?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Did you by any chance consider looking at any of the potential duplicates that the ask a question dialog almost certainly showed when you asked this?

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted. The question is clear and well-formulated. If the reason is that it's a possible duplicate then just vote for close instead of downvote.

Comment: @JustShadow My reasons for downvoting: 1) The Q is badly formatted; it uses image instead of text; 2) There was no attempt to investigate and find a solution, no attempt even to search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To undo an `add` use a `git reset .`

This will unstage all the files in the current folder.

Comment: Why the final `.`? `git reset` works fine and OP did not ask about a specific folder. They said "all files".